# Capacitor / CMOTION/ionic-keycloak-auth CustomTabsIntent not found

Tags: android, angular, capacitor

i trying to convert our angular webapp to an android app with capacitor. We are using SSO Login and i wanted to use the https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cmotion/ionic-keycloak-auth everything is installed and configurated but on build i get this error

```
import android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent;
                             ^
symbol:   class CustomTabsIntent
location: package android.support.customtabs
```

in the BrowserTab class.

i have added the android support and browsertab to the depencies

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'src/main/libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.apache.cordova:framework:$cordovaAndroidVersion"
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
```

}

i have invalidated the cache of android studio but everytime this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the import was wrong
if u have the problem change the import of customtabs to

import androidx.browser.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent